# Core Image - switch transparent for colour

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-image

There sure are a lot of interesting Core Image colour mask questions on here, but most if not all (that's I've seen) have "ready to use", "tailored for the question" snippets of code.

This is great but they are also for the most part written in a short hand fashion, without explanations of what each part is actually doing.

I have an image and part of it is transparent, my goal is to use Core Image to transform the **transparent part into a chosen colour**, *and* the **white part of the image into transparent**.

Could anyone give me some explanations on how to do that? Thanks :)

Comment: Im interesting in transforming the  white part of the image into transparent. If you get an answer, plz @ me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a gist for this, can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/1292152

It's a set of methods in a category on UIImage, it lets you remove and replace colours for an image.